# JavaScript to replace variable in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a function to replace variables in a string with actual values, for example:

```
function replaceUrl(url, data) {}
```

The caller may be:

```
replaceUrl('/task/:module?taskId=:taskId#:hash', {
    module: 'm1',
    taskId: 't1',
    hash: 'h1'
});
```

I think to use RegEx may be simple to implement this, but I'm not very familiar with it.

Can anyone provide a simple way on this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple solution is not to use RegEx at all. Use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var module = 'm1',
    taskId = 't1',
    hash   = 'h1';

var url = `/task/${module}?taskId=${taskId}#${hash}`;
```

```js
var module = 'm1',
    taskId = 't1',
    hash = 'h1';

var url = `/task/${module}?taskId=${taskId}#${hash}`;

document.body.innerHTML = url;
```

Using RegEx:

```
function replaceUrl(url, data) {
    // Create regex using the keys of the replacement object.
    var regex = new RegExp(':(' + Object.keys(data).join('|') + ')', 'g');

    // Replace the string by the value in object
    return url.replace(regex, (m, $1) => data[$1] || m);
}
```

```js
function replaceUrl(url, data) {
    var regex = new RegExp(':(' + Object.keys(data).join('|') + ')', 'g');

    return url.replace(regex, (m, $1) => data[$1] || m);
}


var updatedUrl = replaceUrl('/task/:module?taskId=:taskId#:hash', {
    module: 'm1',
    taskId: 't1',
    hash: 'h1'
});

console.log(updatedUrl);
document.body.innerHTML = updatedUrl;
```

Comment: Note: Template literals will throw reference error and stop processing, if the variable is not defined.

Answer (score 8):

You could write a very simple templating function to achieve this in ES5:

```
function template(string, obj){
  var s = string;
  for(var prop in obj) {
    s = s.replace(new RegExp('{'+ prop +'}','g'), obj[prop]);
  }
  return s;
}

template('/task/{module}?taskId={taskId}#{hash}', {
  module: 'foo', 
  taskId: 2, 
  hash: 'bar'
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5hp2cfv/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the form of [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) that [takes a function as an argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Using your example this could look like:

```
var str = '/task/:module?taskId=:taskId#:hash&:missing';
var obj = {
    module: 'm1',
    taskId: 't1',
    hash: 'h1'
};

function replaceUrl(url, data) {
    var regex = /:(\w+)/g;
    return url.replace(regex, function(match, p1) {
        return data[p1] || ':' + p1;
    });
}

replaceUrl(str, obj); // /task/m1?taskId=t1#h1&:missing
```

This method will handle all parameters you pass values in for and ignore ones that are missing.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple JavaScript function called stringInject to solve this exact problem I was having. It would allow you to do the following. Find links to the code below.

```
var str = "This is a {0} string for {1}"
var newStr = stringInject(str, ["test", "stringInject"]);

// This is a test string for stringInject
```

**NPM / GitHub links:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringinject

https://github.com/tjcafferkey/stringinject

**The Function**

```
function stringInject(str, arr) {
    if (typeof str !== 'string' || !(arr instanceof Array)) {
        return false;
    }

    return str.replace(/({\d})/g, function(i) {
        return arr[i.replace(/{/, '').replace(/}/, '')];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function

```js
function replaceStringVariable(text, data) {
  // Create regex using the keys of the replacement object.
  const regex = new RegExp('\\${(' + Object.keys(data).join('|') + ')}', 'g')
  
  // Replace the string by the value in object
  return text.replace(regex, (m, p1) => data[p1] || m)
}

const newText = replaceStringVariable('hello ${name} and ${nameTwo}', {
  name: "Pedro",
  nameTwo: "Juan"
})

console.log('newText', newText)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).