# Using function context/variables without function arguments

Tags: javascript, eval, template-literals

I'm trying to implement my own [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) functionality (in educational purposes), but I can't understand how it works.

My idea is to extend `String.prototype` with function, that will `eval` every `${}` sequence inside the string. The problem is my new function don't know context (variables inside the string). Here's how I think it should work:

```
String.prototype.smart_eval = function() { /* find all ${} and eval them */ }

function some_function() {
  let a = 1;
  let b = 2;
  return 'A is ${a}, B is ${b}, the sum is ${a + b}'.smart_eval()
}
```

This will cause `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined` since `a` and `b` belong to `some_function()`, not `smart_eval()`. Is there any elegant way to solve this without using function arguments or `.call()` / `.apply()`?

Answer (score 0):

So... It seems I want something, that is not possible. My first idea to solve this as smooth as possible is Python-like function `format`. **I don't qualify this piece of code as 100% working solution**, but maybe somebody will find it usable.

```
String.prototype.format=function(values) {
  let s = this;
  let r = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] == '{') {
      for (let t = i+1; t < s.length; t++) {
        if (s[t] == '}') {
          let d = s.substring(i + 1, t);
          try { d = parseInt(d) }
          catch(err) { d = false } 
          finally {
            if (d !== false) {
              if (values.length >= d + 1) { r += values[d]; i = t; break; }
              else { throw new ReferenceError('Literal is out of values range.') }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      r += s[i] || ''
    }
  }
  return r
}
```

Examples:

```
'Hello {0}!'.format(['there']) // output: 'Hello there!'
'G{0}n{0}ral K{0}n{1}.'.format(['e', 'obi']) // output: 'General Kenobi.'
```

If you don't need **IE11 support** and some other browsers you can use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in function definition:

```
String.prototype.format=function(...values) {
```

And call it in more convenient way (without wrapping parameters into array):

```
'{1} wanna {0}? Let\'s {0}!'.format('play', 'You') // output: 'You wanna play? Let's play!'
```

Comment: code is pretty complicated... simple reg exp is how most people would have solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994853/javascript-to-replace-variable-in-a-string